# How to check if c++ object pointer in pointer array is set

Tags: c++, pointers

i have defined pointers array like this :

```
private:
        PuzzleObj * components[COMPONENT_SIZE];
```

the in the definition file i have one method to set object pointers

```
void ComponentMadiator::Register(PuzzlePartLocation puzzlePartLocation,PuzzleObj* PuzzleObj)
{
    if(components[puzzlePartLocation]!=NULL || components[puzzlePartLocation]->isSet!=NULL || components[puzzlePartLocation]->isSet==true)
    {
        components[puzzlePartLocation] = PuzzleObj;
    }
}
```

and here i check the pointers array that fail when it gets to element that havent bean set
it failes when not set pointer is found in the array element 
and im getting this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00B90646 in Breaker.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDD0D1.

void ComponentMadiator::SendMassage(Massage massage)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < COMPONENT_SIZE; i++)
    {

       if(components[i]!=NULL &&  components[i]->isSet!=NULL)
       {
        if(components[i]->isSet!=false)
        {
         components[i]->Notify(massage);
        }
       }
    }
 }
```

my question is simple how can i check is element in the array contain object pointer ?

UPDATE :
if i dont want to set wite loop all the element , better just using map for the job

Comment: You cannot check that. You must make sure you initialize your data properly in the first place.

Comment: i do initialize  only the when i need to Register object

Comment: I would advise you to read about [pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) and [dynamic memory allocation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)
before continuing

Comment: If you initialize data items in some cases and not in others, then use only initialized data items. If you find it impossible, well, that's too bad. You could have initialized always, which would cost you two lines of code. Then using only initialized data would become trivial. The choice is yours.

Comment: Or you could have done it in idiomatic C++, with an std:: container of smart pointers, and just forget about uninitialized data ever being a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to `class ComponentMadiator`, a constructor which initializes all the entries in the array to `NULL`:

```
ComponentMadiator::ComponentMadiator()
{
    for (int i=0; i<COMPONENT_SIZE; i++)
        components[i] = NULL;
}
```

BTW, there are a few other cavities in your code:

1. Checking `isSet!=NULL` is completely redundant. It appears to be either `true` or `false`.
2. In function `Register`, you are using `PuzzleObj` as both type-name and variable-name.

Comment: is there any other way then loop vi 100 elements ? 
maybe some kind of checker i can add to each class ?

Comment: There is no definite way to assert an uninitialized variable in C/C++.

Comment: Don't forget the || operator which will return false on the null check and  then proceed to check the isSet method of an unallocated object. @user63898 You wanted a && there. Besides having a null object sends a clear information "this object is not set".